# html dropdown box events?

Tags: javascript, html, select, combobox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to pass parameters on onChange of html select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5024056/how-to-pass-parameters-on-onchange-of-html-select)

Been having a bit of a puzzle here. I understand that there's nothing happening on OnChange event in a option tag. But I would like to pass the value of whatever option is selected (1 to 7) into the onChange event in the select tag (in place of what I have there as '7'). What's the best way to do this?

I basically want a font size selection box. The fmtEdit function changes the size.

```
<select onchange="fmtEdit('Icontent','FontSize','7')">
  <option value="0" selected="true">font size</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
</select>
```

Thanks!
gabstero

Comment: Hey, I think [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5024056/how-to-pass-parameters-on-onchange-of-html-select) should answer yours. In the future, please try searching for existing questions and answers before posting a new question.

Comment: I agree with KRyan above, but I think it is also worth mentioning that you did a good job including sufficient source and information to answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try [the link that KRyan mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5024056/how-to-pass-parameters-on-onchange-of-html-select) in the comment under the OP as that should solve your question. If you insist in doing it inline, try this.

```
<select onchange="fmtEdit('Icontent','FontSize',this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
  <option value="0" selected="true">font size</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
</select>
```

Comment: thanks for the tip, mason81 - that did it!