# Uncaught NotSupportedError: The implementation did not support the requested type of object or operation

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am building a web system, where I have a page
called index.php: it is basically jquery functions, html tags, and php includes.

At some point of my file I have div:

```
<div id = "f_list">

<center>
<form>
<select name="file_list" onchange="evaluate(this.value)">
<?php require_once('getfiles.php') ?>
</select>
</form>
</center>
</div>
```

In getfiles.php I am just iterating over lists, putting them into option. 
When I click the list item, it gives me error like this in Chrome and it in not working. 
I made the function so simple like:

```
function evaluate(value)
{
    alert(value);
}
```

But it does not work. Giving me the error: Uncaught NotSupportedError: The implementation did not support the requested type of object or operation
Have any idea, what is wrong? 
Thanks.

Comment: here you can find similar problem and solution:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5024056/how-to-pass-parameters-on-onchange-of-html-select

Comment: Thanks, I did not think about using jquery, you saved my time.