# Getting value from <select> in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

In my Java class I've declared an attribute like this,

```
String option = "<select name='logopt'><option value='fulllog'>Complete Log</option><option value='InfoLog'>INFO Log</option><option value='ErrorLog'>Error Log</option></select><br><br>";
request.setAttribute("LogOption", option);
```

in my `jsp` I've accessed the same like this,

```
<div id="box">${LogOption}</div>
```

Now as this is a select box, I want to get the select box value in `Javascript` How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5024056/how-to-pass-parameters-on-onchange-of-html-select)

In my Java class I've changed what I had to,

```
String option = "<select name='logopt'onchange='xyz(this)'><option value='fulllog'>Complete Log</option><option value='InfoLog'>INFO Log</option><option value='ErrorLog'>Error Log</option></select><br><br>";
request.setAttribute("LogOption", option);
```

in my jsp page, I've added

```
function xyz(sel)
 {
var val = sel.value;
alert(val);
}
```

and now this gives me the value of `select`

Answer (score 1):

Like this -

JavaScript `-->` `var selectVal = document.getElementsByName('logopt')[0].value;`

jQuery `-->`  `var selectVal =  $('select[name=logopt]').val();`

Demo `---->`  http://jsfiddle.net/8t6mP/

Comment: I've added an alert to check, but it is showing un defined on page load and does not show anything whenever the option is changed

Answer (score 0):

you can use attribute selector as specified of jquery as specified by Adil

```
<div>
<select name='logopt'>
    <option value='fulllog'>Complete Log</option>
    <option value='InfoLog'>INFO Log</option>
    <option value='ErrorLog'>Error Log</option>
</select>
</div>
<input type="button" onClick ="return test();"/>
```

and js method

```
function test()
  {
  var x = $('select[name=logopt]').val();
  alert(x);
}
```

jsfiddle link

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hikumar/DX3jK/)