# Can I pass a select value as a param to an onchange function?

Tags: javascript, onchange

Is this possible using some combination of javascript and html?

```
<select onchange="myFunction(valueOfThisSelector)">
    <option value="op1">Op1</option>
    <option value="op2">Op2</option>
    <option value="op3">Op3</option>
</select>
```

I would prefer if the solution is achieved without using element ids, because I want to be able to apply this to many selectors.  If the value reference can be achieved in the `myFunction()` script that is also an option, so long as it doesn't use `document.getElementById()`.

Comment: At least one of the answers on [How to pass parameters on onChange of html select](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5024056/215552) does not use an ID.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just pass `this` as parameter, then get the value from it :

```js
function myFunction(current_select){
    alert( current_select.value );
}
```

```html
<select onchange="myFunction(this)">
    <option value="op1">Op1</option>
    <option value="op2">Op2</option>
    <option value="op3">Op3</option>
</select>
```

Or pass the value directly :

```js
function myFunction(selected_value){
    alert( selected_value );
}
```

```html
<select onchange="myFunction(this.value)">
    <option value="op1">Op1</option>
    <option value="op2">Op2</option>
    <option value="op3">Op3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Or just `<select onchange="myFunction(this.value)">`

Comment: Thanks for your intervention @Robiseb .. updated my answer