# How through select to add request parameters?

Tags: html

I have such a question. Is it possible to send a parameter with `<select>` in any way? I tried to do it on `onchange` but that does not work

I am tried this way:

```
<select name="locale" onchange="this.value">
    <option value="${requestScope['javax.servlet.forward.request_uri']}?lang=en_US" ${pageContext.request.locale eq 'en_US' ? 'selected' : ''}><fmt:message key="english"/></option>
    <option value="${requestScope['javax.servlet.forward.request_uri']}?lang=ru" ${pageContext.request.locale eq 'ru' ? 'selected' : ''}><fmt:message key="russian"/></option>
</select>
<a href="${requestScope['javax.servlet.forward.request_uri']}?lang=en_US"><fmt:message key="english"/></a>
<a href="${requestScope['javax.servlet.forward.request_uri']}?lang=ru"><fmt:message key="russian"/></a>
```

With links, everything works fine, but how do I send the parameter via `<select>`

Comment: What do you mean, *"send the parameter via `<select>`"*? Could you please improve your question?

Comment: do you want like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40272039/can-i-pass-a-select-value-as-a-param-to-an-onchange-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the below code to select the current value in the dropdown and then take actions upon it.

```
<select id="locale">
    <option value="${requestScope['javax.servlet.forward.request_uri']}?lang=en_US" ${pageContext.request.locale eq 'en_US' ? 'selected' : ''}><fmt:message key="english"/></option>
    <option value="${requestScope['javax.servlet.forward.request_uri']}?lang=ru" ${pageContext.request.locale eq 'ru' ? 'selected' : ''}><fmt:message key="russian"/></option>
    </select>

    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function () { 
     $('#locale').change(function(){ 
      var localeVal = $(this).val();//gets the current selected dropdown value 
     });
    });
    </script>
```