# how to get the value of select element via inline javascript

Tags: javascript, html, function, select, onchange

when clicking this select element, the inline call "onchange" should call a javascript function:

```
<select onchange="if (this.selectedIndex) do_something();">
  <option value=1>1</option>
  <option value=2>2</option>
</select>
```

basically how do i submit the option selected to 'do_something()' function?  or in the function how can I obtain the option value selected?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass parameters on onChange of html select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5024056/how-to-pass-parameters-on-onchange-of-html-select)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get selected value in dropdown list using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may try this :

```js
function do_something(e) {
  alert(e);
}
```

```html
<select onchange="if (this.selectedIndex) do_something(this.value);">
  <option value=1>1</option>
  <option value=2>2</option>
  <option value=3>3</option>
  <option value=4>4</option>
</select>
```

You may notice that i won't work for 1 because of **selectedIndex** which is equal to 0 for the first index (the value 1)

so more generic it can be :

```js
function do_something(e) {
  //we make do test on the element e
  alert(e.value);
}
```

```html
<select onchange="do_something(this);">
  <option value=1>1</option>
  <option value=2>2</option>
  <option value=3>3</option>
  <option value=4>4</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function do_something(i){
  console.log(i);
}
```

```html
<select onchange="do_something(this.selectedIndex);">
  <option value=1>1</option>
  <option value=2>2</option>
</select>
```

Try adding it as a parameter in the do_something function.