# Using a javascript select dropdown. On change event won't trigger

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using W3s custom-select found here: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_custom_select.asp

However, when using an onchange event it is not recognizing the call. I'm sure the dropdown needs a line of code to trigger the change. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

HTML:

```
<div id="custom-select" style="width:100%;">
    <select id="altaddresstype" onchange="altcountry(this.value)">
        <option value=disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Domestic</option>
        <option value="Domesticalt">Domestic</option>
        <option value="Foreignalt">Foreign</option>
        <option value="Foreignzipalt">Foreign Zip Last</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Function:

```
function altcountry(val){
    var altaddtype = val
    alert(altaddtype);
}
```

W3 Javascript:

```
var x, i, j, selElmnt, a, b, c;
/*look for any elements with the class "custom-select":*/
x = document.getElementsByClassName("custom-select");
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  selElmnt = x[i].getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
  /*for each element, create a new DIV that will act as the selected item:*/
  a = document.createElement("DIV");
  a.setAttribute("class", "select-selected");
  a.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[selElmnt.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
  x[i].appendChild(a);
  /*for each element, create a new DIV that will contain the option list:*/
  b = document.createElement("DIV");
  b.setAttribute("class", "select-items select-hide");
  for (j = 1; j < selElmnt.length; j++) {
    /*for each option in the original select element,
    create a new DIV that will act as an option item:*/
    c = document.createElement("DIV");
    c.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[j].innerHTML;
    c.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        /*when an item is clicked, update the original select box,
        and the selected item:*/
        var y, i, k, s, h;
        s = this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
        h = this.parentNode.previousSibling;
        for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
          if (s.options[i].innerHTML == this.innerHTML) {
            s.selectedIndex = i;
            h.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
            y = this.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("same-as-selected");
            for (k = 0; k < y.length; k++) {
              y[k].removeAttribute("class");
            }
            this.setAttribute("class", "same-as-selected");
            break;
          }
        }
        h.click();
    });
    b.appendChild(c);
  }
  x[i].appendChild(b);
  a.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      /*when the select box is clicked, close any other select boxes,
      and open/close the current select box:*/
      e.stopPropagation();
      closeAllSelect(this);
      this.nextSibling.classList.toggle("select-hide");
      this.classList.toggle("select-arrow-active");
  });
}
function closeAllSelect(elmnt) {
  /*a function that will close all select boxes in the document,
  except the current select box:*/
  var x, y, i, arrNo = [];
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("select-items");
  y = document.getElementsByClassName("select-selected");
  for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    if (elmnt == y[i]) {
      arrNo.push(i)
    } else {
      y[i].classList.remove("select-arrow-active");
    }
  }
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (arrNo.indexOf(i)) {
      x[i].classList.add("select-hide");
    }
  }
}
/*if the user clicks anywhere outside the select box,
then close all select boxes:*/
document.addEventListener("click", closeAllSelect);
```

Comment: let us see your code . so that we can figure out

Comment: Add the code which is not working as well.

Comment: Please include a [mcve] **in the question itself** not only on an external site.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass parameters on onChange of html select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5024056/how-to-pass-parameters-on-onchange-of-html-select)

Comment: @jasinthpremkumar code added.

Comment: you are just missing a "`;`: in altcountry()

Answer (score 1):

This works fine?
HTML:

```
<div id="custom-select" class="custom-select" style="width:100%;">
    <select id="altaddresstype" onchange="altcountry()">
        <option value=disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Domestic</option>
        <option value="Domesticalt">Domestic</option>
        <option value="Foreignalt">Foreign</option>
        <option value="Foreignzipalt">Foreign Zip Last</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function altcountry(){
    var val = document.getElementById("altaddresstype").value;
    alert(val)
}
```

CSS:

```
/*the container must be positioned relative:*/
.custom-select {
  position: relative;
  font-family: Arial;
}
.custom-select select {
  display: none; /*hide original SELECT element:*/
}
.select-selected {
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}
/*style the arrow inside the select element:*/
.select-selected:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 14px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 6px solid transparent;
  border-color: #fff transparent transparent transparent;
}
/*point the arrow upwards when the select box is open (active):*/
.select-selected.select-arrow-active:after {
  border-color: transparent transparent #fff transparent;
  top: 7px;
}
/*style the items (options), including the selected item:*/
.select-items div,.select-selected {
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-color: transparent transparent rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}
/*style items (options):*/
.select-items {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 99;
}
/*hide the items when the select box is closed:*/
.select-hide {
  display: none;
}
.select-items div:hover, .same-as-selected {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

Adjust your function and call to this and should work with their custom code on W3

Comment: That does work when the div is not in place. When the custom-select div is in place the onchange no longer calls the function.

Comment: This works fine. It's in jsbin on my PC right now. What do you mean by not in place

Comment: when I remove the div the alerts come up just fine but the drop down is no longer styled. When the div is added for the style the alerts no longer popup. I tried everything you had here in a jsbin and still had the same issue. Also thank you for taking some time and helping me troubleshoot this.

Comment: What are you aiming to get? Maybe it can be re-written differently with less CSS and useless JS if you're not using the example fully on W3. Do you just want the select styled differently?

Comment: Yeah, just trying to have it styled a little more than CSS only offers for select boxes.

Comment: I was able to add an event lister to the JS to handle this. Thanks again for the time.

Comment: @Propel Can u post the solution here?