# How to pass Value from a <select> in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to pass the selected value of a `<select>` in the `onChange` function.
I have tried this SO [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5024056/how-to-pass-parameters-on-onchange-of-html-select), but `this` and `this.value` don't work. I know the question is kinda old...

```
setShippingMethod(obj) {
    console.log('Shipping method ' + JSON.stringify(obj));
    this.state.defaultMethod = obj.value;
    this.props.setShippingMethod(obj.value);
}

render() {
    const shippingMethods = this.state.shippingMethods;
    const defaultMethod = this.state.defaultMethod;        

    return (
        <aside id="checkout" className="block col-1">
            <h1>Shipping</h1>
            <div className="row">
                <select id="comboMethod" onChange={setShippingMethod(this)} value={!!defaultMethod ? null : defaultMethod.trim()}>
                    {shippingMethods.map(method => { return <option key={method.shipmthd.trim()} value={method.shipmthd.trim()}>{method.shipmthd.trim()}</option>} )}
                </select>
            </div>
        </aside>
    );
}
```

My line `console.log('Shipping method ' + JSON.stringify(obj))` generates an error "Uncaught TypeError: cyclic object value" and the message seems to be `this` still refers to the entire (in my case) `modal`. Is there a newer way to do this? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using events Listeners in react, you get an event object. Their You can access the value that entered to the element with e.target.value.

```
setShippingMethod(e) {
    console.log('Shipping method ' + JSON.stringify(e.target.value));
    //...rest of the code
}

render() {
    const shippingMethods = this.state.shippingMethods;
    const defaultMethod = this.state.defaultMethod;        

    return (
        <aside id="checkout" className="block col-1">
            <h1>Shipping</h1>
            <div className="row">
                <select id="comboMethod" onChange={setShippingMethod} value={!!defaultMethod ? null : defaultMethod.trim()}>
                    {shippingMethods.map(method => { return <option key={method.shipmthd.trim()} value={method.shipmthd.trim()}>{method.shipmthd.trim()}</option>} )}
                </select>
            </div>
        </aside>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this is always going to be a reference to the class while you are in class.
if you want to pass the selected option value you need something like

```js
onChange={(e) => {setShippingMethod(e.target.value)}}
```